# how to modify multiple cells in a loop in R without losing formatting?

Tags: r, loops, xlsx

Disclaimer: R noob here!

On a high level, I am trying to convert pdf to xls ;) The pdf is well formatted, no surprises expected. At one point I am trying to modify multiple cells using xlsx package in a loop. I've got a variable list of 3 - 5 elements and want to change the content of 7th column in .xls file, starting with 14th row. The list is coming from a PDF file (src.pdf below).

Here's the code:

```
library(xlsx)
library(pdftools)
library(stringr)
library(tabulizer)
library(tidyverse)

# for example data, separately download src.xls from https://file-examples-com.github.io/uploads/2017/02/file_example_XLS_100.xls, i. e. using wget -O src.xls https://file-examples-com.github.io/uploads/2017/02/file_example_XLS_100.xls

src <- xlsx::loadWorkbook(file = "src.xls")
sheets <- getSheets(src)
rows  <- getRows(sheets$List1)
cc <- getCells(rows)

pdf_path <- "src.pdf"

# dest <- extract_tables("src.pdf", output="data.frame", area = list(c(163, 315, 217, 459)), guess = FALSE, header = FALSE)

dest <- extract_tables("https://unec.edu.az/application/uploads/2014/12/pdf-sample.pdf", output="data.frame", area=list(c(195,103,376,515)), guess = FALSE, header = FALSE)


#use as
#dest[[c(1,1)]][1]
#dest[[c(1,1)]][2]
#...

row = 0
for (i in 1:length(dest[[1]]$V1))
{
row = i+13
setCellValue(paste0("cc$`",row,".7`"), value = dest[[c(1,1)]][i])
}
```

This returns

> Error in .jcall(cell, "V", "setCellValue", value) :
> RcallMethod: cannot determine object class

Any ideas how to use setCellValue in a loop? I am open to using different modules as well, as long as they keep the formatting of the source .xls.
Thank you!

Comment: Are you able to share example input data?

Comment: updated with reproducible examples